# Editing photoshop images in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I edited a b/w image in photoshop with the effects gallery and saved it. I opened up illustrator and placed it behind some text I created. Now I'm trying to add a  fill and stroke around it to match the text stroke, but I'm unable do it in the appearance panel.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a pain to do this.  You could always create empty rectangles the same size as your images and then apply the styles/strokes to those, but I'll guide you through adding strokes *to* the images below

- Select the image you wish to add a stroke to and open the Appearance Panel
- Click Add New Stroke, located at the bottom left of the panel (it looks like a hollow square)

[image]

You can edit the stroke properties, but nothing will appear.  To get the stroke to show, you need to create a shape.

- Select the stroke effect in the Appearance Panel and then go to FX > Convert to Shape > Rectangle

[image]

You can add an offset, if you want some white space.  Otherwise, make sure Extra Width and Extra Height are both 0

[image]

Edit your stroke by clicking on it in the Appearance Panel

Comment: I tried it, but instead of putting the stroke around the image, it put the stroke around the selection box.   One thing I did notice is that it says unembed at the top.  Not sure how to fix that either.

Comment: @louiss so you don't have a rectangular image?  If your image is oddly shaped (a cutout image with transparent background, for example), you're probably better off just doing the stroke work in PS; it's much easier there.

Comment: Thanks for the help and awesome example images.. When I got back home. I scrapped it and tried again from scratch.  I Just opened the file in Illustrator and then: Object>Image Trace>Make. Chose 3 color. and then Object>Image Trace>Expand. It Worked.

Answer (score -3):

You need to make sure that the image/psd is embedded before you can perform actions on it.

[image]

Comment: Not true. Even an embedded image will still require extra steps to add a stroke